# PHP curl post parsing error

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send data via curl by POST.

Here's what I have done

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://lc-api.sdl.com/translate");
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-type:application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization:LC apiKey=QidCWRGQ%2BHsdzGE6rrBgiw%3D%3D';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"text=Bonjour&from=fra&to=eng");  //Post Fields
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

   curl_close ($ch);

   print  $server_output ;
```

I get an error indicating

```
Error parsing json at column:6 line:1 offset:-1
```

Here is the working Curl request

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: LC apiKey=QidCWRGQ%2BHsdzGE6rrBgiw%3D%3D" -d '{"text":"Bonjour", "from" : "fra", "to" : "eng"}' https://lc-api.sdl.com/translate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://lc-api.sdl.com/translate");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type:application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization:LC apiKey=QidCWRGQ%2BHsdzGE6rrBgiw%3D%3D';

$data = array("text" => "Bonjour", "from" => "fra", "to" => "eng");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);  //Post Fields
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print  $server_output ;
?>
```

Post fields in `json_encode` format.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after I changed it

Comment: I got `{"partialTranslation":false,"from":"fra","to":"eng","wordCount":1,"charCount":7,"translation":"Hello"}` result. Is this result as per your requirement? Clear your browser cache and then check.

Comment: Yeah ankit this is the desired result

Comment: I run above code and it worked on my localhost. Are you still getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

full code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://lc-api.sdl.com/translate");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type:application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization:LC apiKey=QidCWRGQ%2BHsdzGE6rrBgiw%3D%3D';

$data = array("text" => "Bonjour", "from" => "fra", "to" => "eng");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);  //Post Fields
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($server_output );
?>
```